# EJS template not recognizing variable even if it is passed to it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

Even after passing the values to the ejs template, I am getting an error stating that the variables are not defined. I tried restarting the server but it didn't work.

flightsController.js:

```
if (flight.length > 0) {
    if (returnTicket) {
        const returnFlight = await Flights.find({
            sourceIATA: destinationIATA,
            destinationIATA: sourceIATA,
        });

        if (returnFlight.length > 0) {
            res.render("flights", { flight, returnFlight });
        } else {
            res.render("flights", { flight, noReturnFlights: true });
        }
    } else {
        res.render("flights", { flight });
    }
} else {
    res.render("flights", { noFlightsAvailable: true });
}
```

flights.ejs:

```
<% if (flight && flight.length > 0) { %>
    <h2>Flights:</h2>
    <ul>
      <% flight.forEach(flight => { %>
        <li>Flight ID: <%= flight.flightId %></li>
        <li>Source City: <%= flight.sourceCity %></li>
        <li>Destination City: <%= flight.destinationCity %></li>
        <!-- Display other flight details as needed -->
        <br>
      <% }); %>
    </ul>
  <% } %>

  <% if (noReturnFlights) { %>
    <h2>No Return Flights Available</h2>
  <% } %>

  <% if (noFlightsAvailable) { %>
    <h2>No Flights Available</h2>
  <% } %>
```

Example error (this is happening to all the variables):

`flight is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

In the flightsController.js file, different local variables are set for the view when using res.render() calls. For example:

1. `res.render("flights", { flight, returnFlight });`
2. `res.render("flights", { flight, noReturnFlights: true });`
3. `res.render("flights", { flight });`
4. `res.render("flights", { noFlightsAvailable: true });`

However, the view file expects specific local variables `(flight, returnFlight, noReturnFlights, and noFlightsAvailable)` to be passed to it. In the first case, since noReturnFlights wasn't passed but defined in the view file, it throws an error. Instead make a uniform call like this, 
`res.render("flights", { flight , returnFlight: null,noReturnFlights: true , noFlightsAvailable: true });`

Answer (score 0):

In the flightsController.js file, change your code appropriately:

```js
if (flight.length > 0) {
    if (returnTicket) {
        const returnFlight = await Flights.find({
            sourceIATA: destinationIATA,
            destinationIATA: sourceIATA,
        });

        if (returnFlight.length > 0) {
           res.render("flights",{
                flight : flight ,
                returnFlight: returnFlight
            });
        } else {
            res.render("flights",{
                flight : flight ,
                noReturnFlights: true
            });
        }
    } else {
        res.render("flights",{
          flight : flight ,
        });
    }
} else {
    res.render("flights",{
      flight : flight ,
      noFlightsAvailable: true
    });
}
```